# Finite Summation of Fractional Factorial Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, factorial

Is there a closed form solution for the following series? (Without Using Gamma Function):
$$
S=\sum _{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(i+1)!}
$$

Comment: A generating function for this sum is given by $$S = [z^n] (e^z-1-z) / (1-z)$$. This does not involve the gamma function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that
$$n!\,e=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{n!}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{k!}+\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{n!}{k!}$$
The first sum on the RHS is always an integer since $n\geq k$. The second sum satisfies
$$\begin{align} \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{n!}{k!}
&=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}+\cdots\\
&<\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n+1) (n+1)(n+1)}+\cdots\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)^k}\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\\
&\leq1
\end{align}$$
when $n\geq1$. Hence we have
$$\lfloor n!\,e\rfloor=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{k!}\\
\implies \frac{\lfloor n!\,e\rfloor}{n!}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}\\
\implies \frac{\lfloor n!\,e\rfloor}{n!}-2=\sum _{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(k+1)!}
$$

Comment: Just to note a minor extension that I obtained recently following this prescription:
$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{m^{n-k}n!}{k!} = \lfloor m^n n! e^{\frac{1}{m}}\rfloor$

Answer (score 4):

Let's rewrite this as $\;\displaystyle S=\sum _{j=0}^{n} \frac{1}{j!}-2\;$ then prove that 
$$\sum _{j=0}^{n} \frac{1}{j!}=\frac{\lfloor e\; n!\rfloor}{n!}$$

Comment: Can you explain it a bit. Is $$\sum _{j=0}^{n} \frac{1}{j!}=\frac{\lfloor e\; n!\rfloor}{n!}$$ a standard result?

Comment: wonderful... any idea how to prove?

Comment: @user3127040: To prove it consider the remainder of the exponential expansion and multiply it by $n!$ you should obtain something like $\;\displaystyle \frac 1{(n+1)}+ \frac 1{(n+1)(n+2)} +\cdots$ that you may bound with a geometric series smaller than $1$.

Comment: @Integrator: Yes a standard result perhaps from the [irrationality of $e$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_e_is_irrational) (possibly earlier I don't know...).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: Thanks a lot.