# Alternating series of reciprocals of factorials

Tags: summation, factorial, closed-form

Consider the sum:
$$ \frac{(-1)^2}{2!}+\frac{(-1)^3}{3!}+\frac{(-1)^4}{4!}+\ldots+ \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}.  $$ 
Does there exist a nice closed form of such sum?

Comment: Compare to $e^x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(UPDATED)
Concerning the finite sum :
$$\tag{1}S_n:=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$
we have simply : $$\tag{2} S_n=\frac 1{n!}\left[\frac{n!}e\right]=\frac{!n}{n!}$$
with $[x]$ the [nearest integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_integer_function) (i.e. the round function) and $\,!n\,$ the [number of derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Counting_derangements) for $n$ elements
(added from [Wood's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2086060/21783)  (+1) in the related thread for additional properties).

To prove this directly you may use a method similar to the one proposed in this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281543/finite-summation-of-fractional-factorial-series).

The idea is that the remaining terms of the Maclaurin expansion of $\,e^{-1}\;n!\,$ (after the $n$ first terms) are : $\;\displaystyle \frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)}+ \frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)(n+2)} +\cdots\;\ $ and thus with absolute value bounded by $\dfrac 12$ for $n>1$ that will disappear with the round function.

Answer (score 2):

Take the hint that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {x^n}{n!} =e^x $$ What can you conclude from this? Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Given series is exponential series, so you have

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac {x^k}{k!} =e^x $

[You have to also see this for different type of series.](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://homepages.gac.edu/~holte/courses/mcs256/documents/summation/top10sums.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiju53WzKrRAhUHro8KHXmKCTUQFggnMAE&usg=AFQjCNE97DJhp_AGmF8H0ojFSmNKfXTtww)