# Prove that $n-1$ divides $n!\left(1+\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\right)$

Tags: summation, divisibility

> Prove that $n-1$ divides $n!\left(1+\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\right)$.

There is a sequence: $a_1=1$, $a_{n}=n\cdot a_{n-1}+(-1)^n$. The question is to prove that $n-1$ divides $a_n$.

My approach was to notice the general formula for $a_n$, namely:

$$ a_n=n!\left(1+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\right) $$

(this is trivial to verify just by plugging into the recursive relation). Now, how should I show that $n-1$ divides $$n!\left(1+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\right)\ ?$$

At first, I thought it was trivial, then I noticed that the term in the parentheses is not an integer. My question is then:

- how to prove the claim that $n-1$ divides $a_n$ *using the general formula*,

and then:

- maybe it can be done only using the recurrence relation?

Comment: Hint: Can you prove that $n-1$ divides $$n!\,\left(1+\sum_{k=2}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\right)\ ?$$ Can you prove that $n-1$ divides $$n!\,\left(\frac1{(n-1)!}-\frac1{n!}\right)\ ?$$

Comment: In your first line isn't it $\;a_{n+1}=na_n+(-1)^n\;$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the formulas for [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement):

$$!n = (n - 1) \left[!(n-1) + !(n-2)\right]$$

and

$$!n = n! \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$

We have:

$$\begin{align}n!\left(1+\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\right) &= n!\left(1+\sum\limits_{k=\color{red}{0}}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\right)\\
&= n!+!n\\
&= n(n-1)(n-2)!+(n - 1) \left[!(n-1) + !(n-2)\right]\\
&= \color{blue}{(n-1)}\left[n(n-2)!+!(n-1) + !(n-2)\right]\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

From the recursion we have that $$a_n = n(n-1)a_{n-2} + (n-1)(-1)^{n-1}. $$ Hence by induction $a_n$ is divisble by $n-1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (note this holds true for the first few cases.)