# Investigate the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}f\left(n+1\right)}{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

> Define $f(n)=n+\frac 1 {n^2}$. Consider the following sum-
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}f\left(n+1\right)}{n!}$$
> Investigate whether this series converges. If it does, then find the value to which it converges.

I have calculated that the general term is
$$T_n=\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\frac{(n+1)^3+1}{(n+1)^2\times n!}$$
although this does not help in proceeding anymore.

It doesn't look like a very difficult question, but I can't get a hold over it.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that I have already figured out that the series converges using Ratio Test. What I want to know, is the point to which it converges.

Stirling's Approximation has been suggested in the comments although I don't see how to use it to get the convergence point.

Comment: Are you aware of the growth rate of factorial?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz Stirling? Yes, I am.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I forgot to mention that I could figure out the convergence using ratio test, what I couldn't do is the where it converges part.

Comment: @AdamRubinson yes, of course. I apologise for the mistake.

Comment: Why the downvote though?

Comment: I downvote questions if I think they are of sufficiently poor quality. Now your question doe not meet this threshold, I have removed my downvote.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2084405/alternating-series-of-reciprocals-of-factorials

Comment: You can find out [**here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+from+n+%3D+1+to+infinity+of+%28%28-1%29%5E%28n%2B1%29+*+%28%28n%2B1%29+%2B+1%2F%28n%2B1%29%5E2%29%29%2Fn%21) on WolframAlpha what this converges to, but it is more involved than a class broaching the ratio test would reasonably expect. (You need the exponential integral, Ei(x), and $\gamma$ to express it in "closed" form.)

Comment: Multiply each term by $x^n$. Use the series for $e^x$ and the fact that $f(x) \mapsto x f'(x)$ multiplies the coefficient of $x^n$ by $n$. I don't believe the answer has a closed form without using something like an incomplete gamma function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the convergence, to have the result, you can split the sum since both of the terms are converging.

You have :

$$S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{n}{n!} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!n^2}.$$

The first term can be rewritten as :

$$  \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{(n-1)!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+2}\frac{1}{n!} = (-1)^2e^{-1} = e^{-1}.$$

The first term is an hypergeometric function. From the notation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function , the second term can be rewritten as (wolfromalpha) :

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!n^2} = -_3F_3(1,1,1,2,2,2;-1) \approx -0.89.$$

Finally,

$$S = e^{-1}- {_3}F_3(1,1,1,2,2,2;-1).$$

Perhaps you can get a more simple proof. Hope it helps.

Comment: I think that in the expression $S=$ it shoyld be a plus instead of a minus

Comment: I guess it's the best one can do (+1)!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the ratio test, your serie is even absolutely convergent.

You have :
$$|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}| = \frac{1}{n+1}\frac{n+2+\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}}{n+1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}}.$$

You can see that the second fraction tends to $1$ whereas the first clearly tends to 0. The ratio tends then to 0 and the serie converges.

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but as I have included in the question, I forgot to mention that I have already figured out that the series converges using Ratio Test. What I want to know, is the point to which it converges.