# Explicit definition of sequence of partial sums of 1/n!

Tags: sequences-and-series

is there an explicit definition of the following sequence? $$s(n)=\sum_{i=0}^n \frac1{i!}$$
Sincerely

Comment: It would be a form of double summation

Comment: yes there is an explicit term for this sum

Comment: Yes see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281543/finite-summation-of-fractional-factorial-series) and (for the alternate sum) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2084487/21783).

Comment: why don't you add a few terms together?  See if anything jumps out at you