# Approximate sum of finite set of terms in Taylor series for exponential

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function

This question was inspired by the following post -  "[Finite Summation of Fractional Factorial Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281543/finite-summation-of-fractional-factorial-series)"
$$ $$

We know already that $$e^x=\frac{x^0}{0!}+\frac{x^1}{1!}+...$$

Suppose we want to approximate the sum of a well-defined subset of terms,

Can we (1) Pick out a limited 'run' of terms in $e^x$ such as $$\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}$$ and (2) Can we, "sieve" those terms to get this kind of thing$$\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^7}{7!}$$In this case, the distance is $2=(7-5)=(5-3)$, $1^{st}$ term index is 3, count of terms is 3.

Comment: what do you meant by distance is 2 ?

Comment: Obviously you *can* do whatever you want. But what's the point of doing it? Is it to get a good approximation for cheaper? This will typically fail terribly because typically the terms are somewhat close to monotone. For example the terms in the sum for $e^x$ for $x>0$ are generally significant for $n$ within about $3\sqrt{x}$ of $x$ (i.e. $e^x \approx \sum_{n=\max \{ 0,\lfloor x-3\sqrt{x} \rfloor \}}^{\lceil x+3\sqrt{x} \rceil} \frac{x^n}{n!}$).

Comment: What do you really want to do? What is the point of this?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question note that
$$
\sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=\exp(x)-x-\frac{x^2}{2!}-\dotsb-\frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}
$$
for $k\geq 1$.