# Finite sum of $1/(n!)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, arithmetic

I know that an infinite series $1/(n!)$ converges to $e$, but how do I find finite sums? For example, the first 100 members, or the first 1000, and so on?

Comment: You probably can’t in any closed form better than $\sum_{n=1}^m\frac1{m!}.$ I suppose you can write it as $$e-\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty}\frac1{n!}$$

Comment: see for example [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281543) to get $\dfrac{\lfloor e\; n!\rfloor}{n!}$

Comment: $e$ is a good approximation for $n\geq 100$

Comment: Hi @JeanMarie and sorry (just noticed your comment and was offline). Cheers anyway,

Comment: What other answer do you expect other than the simply add them up one by one?  Why do you thing there'd be any other answer?

Comment: @Raymond Manzoni Nice exchange yesterday. Maybe, you will be interested by this past answer of mine: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3883132 (to a different question). Cheers.

Comment: @JeanMarie: neat analysis (and links) of yours concerning the zeros of the partial exponential sum, thanks to share! Cheers,

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there is no analytical expression, but using the remainder formula for the Taylor expansion of the exponential,

$$e-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}=\frac c{(n+1)!}$$ where $1<c<e$. For $n=100$ or $n=1000$, this is microscopic.

---

**Update:**

From the link given by Raymond, we have

$$c=(n+1){\{e\,n!\}}=1+\frac1{n+2}+\frac1{(n+2)(n+3)}+\cdots<1+\frac1{n+1},$$ which obviously tends to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, but finite sums are often referred to as [partial sums](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialSum.html).

One can obtain a partial sum by simply setting a finite number as the upper limit of the sum (compared to infinity).

This way, one merely iterates through the appropriate values of $x$ (in this case) to obtain the partial sum (or finite series)

For example:

$\sum_{x=1}^3 \frac{1}{x!} = \frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}=1+\frac{2}{3}$

This can be generalized as:

$\sum_{x=n}^m f(x) = f(n)+f(n+1)+f(n+2)...+f(m)$

where $f$ is an function from the integers to the reals.

Comment: Need to find the value 2*2019/(1+1/2+1/(2*3)+...+1/(1*2*...2019) , I know the answer is 2010, so the sum is 1/n! From 1 to 2019 is equal to (2*2019) / 2010, but I don't understand how it was calculated