# What is the complexity of this algorithm's formula?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

I managed to determine the equation of my algorithm, which generates a graph and I tested it it works well, but I don't know how to determine the time and space complexity of it based on this formula:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n!}{(n-i)!}
$$
with $1\leq n\leq 8$

This formula calculates the number of edges of the graph according to the input $n$.

Comment: what does complexity mean in this context?

Comment: a simpler formula would be $\,\operatorname{floor}(e*n! - 1)\,$ from [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A007526) or more clearly from this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1281543).

Comment: I mean as an expression of O(), I am refering to this complexity [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)

Comment: Thank you @Raymond Manzoni, I didn't know of this OEIS website ! Yet I am still unsure what O() complexity it would be ... I believe it is O(n!) or near this, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: @Gabriel C: You are simply adding the first terms of the exponential of $1$ (up to $\frac 1{(n-1)!}$) and multiplying by $n!$ so that you obtain indeed an $O(n!)$ expression.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation !

Comment: What algorithm are you wanting to find the time complexity of? Is it the algorithm with input $n$ and output the value of your sum?